# how do i know how big i should make a picture for the different android res (hdpi,mdpi,ldpi)?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a problem, i'm working on a android application for a 7' tablet. now i want also smartphones to display these application. the problem is that i dont know how to resize the images in the right size.

for example my tablet has some images in the hdpi folder which are 300x300px how do i know how big the pictures in the mdpi or ldpi should be?

i'm a little bit confused.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four generalized densities

use this [link](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) for generating drawables

Comment: you mean first make it 8 and then scale it down to 6,4 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the answer :

```
   Screen Size             Ratio
```

ldpi : 240x320            --> 36 * 36

mdpi : 320x480            --> 48 * 48

hdpi : 480x800            --> 72 * 72

xhdpi : 1280x800..        --> 96 8 96 (for the new coming phones)

Answer (score 0):

This thread should help you :
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Look at the "Range of screens supported" section and at the end of the article (the table) :)

**Normally the screen sizes should be :**

ldpi : 240x320

mdpi : 320x480

hdpi : 480x800

xhdpi : 1280x800...(for the new coming phones)

Basically, if your images are not too much complicated, and if you have them in the hdpi format, the system will resize them automatically (test on some emulators if you want).
If they are more complex, the best way is to draw screens with the different dimensions in photoshop (or an other image software) to re-draw your images at the good dimension.